# Checking if post was made within the past week

Tags: php, html

Okay so what I'm trying to do is have NEW next to the header of the news title if the post was made within a week.
Here is my current code:

```
$time = date('F j - G:i:s a', $news['n_time']);
$weekago = $news['n_time'] - 604800;
$now = date();
if ($now-$weekago < 604800) {
$new = " <span class='label label-default'>New</span>";
}
```

Is that correct?
EDIT: The problem I am having is it's displaying new even if the post was made back in june

Comment: Are you asking the question without even trying? Please post a question when you have a problem that you cannot figure out how to solve.

Comment: Sorry regulus I updated the OP

Comment: nl-x I already said sorry and I updated with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time = date('F j - G:i:s a', $news['n_time']);
$weekago = $news['n_time'] - 604800;
$now = date();
if ($now-$weekago < 604800) {
    $new = " <span class='label label-default'>New</span>";
}
```

First of all, you set $time, but never use it.

Second. $weekago should be calculated with $now

Third. date() returns a formatted string. For a timestamp, use date_timestamp_get(date_create()). BTW, is $news['n_time'] a timestamp as well ?

Try it like this:

```
$now = date_timestamp_get(date_create());
$weekago = $now - 604800;
if ($news['n_time'] > $weekago) {
    $new = " <span class='label label-default'>New</span>";
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, $time is part of something else.. Also, I tried it but it's displaying New still from very old posts EDIT: I tried with date_timestamp_get(date_create()); and it worked now! Thanks!